# Laravel API login with username and token

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5.1

I am developing a laravel API(**MyAPI**) with the 5.1 version.I am connecting to this API from a widget which hosted in another website.it has a separate API(**hostAPI**). I need to authenticate user when widget loaded.

following are my requirement.

" When the widget loads it will attempt to authenticate. It will send a request to the MyAPI with

```
{
 username: username,
 token: token
}
```

**MyAPI** will POST this information on to the **hostAPI**. This will return either success or a 401.

On sucess, we log the user in. We may need to create an account if an user with that name does not exist"

how can i auth a user with only username and a token key
[image]

Comment: If you are developing new app use latest Laravel not the old one.

Comment: Laravel API, take a look at Lumen. https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: @Kyslik: this is an old app.not a new one

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good practice, I would suggest using something like a [JWT](https://jwt.io/), get the user to login using Username/Password then return the token in all future requests.

Comment: You need to approach this from different angle, APIs *should* be stateless so any authentication you do should be done **per request**. You want to take a look at Laravel OAuth package. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not a good practice to login user by user interface. 
But it is an option and maybe in your case you can use that.

So you know only the username, and token.

I think you can query the database based on you username and token . find the user and login the selected one :)

Example:

```
$user=User::where('username',$username)->where('token',$token)->first();
Auth::login($user);
return  Auth::user();
```

In case you want to create the user if it does not exist:

```
$user=User::where('username',$username)->where('token',$token)->firstOrCreate(['username' => $username,'token'=>$token]);
```